# Use constants with Perl threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

`threads::shared` doesn't allow to share constants between threads.
Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html):
"When a constant is used in an expression, Perl replaces it with its value at compile time(...)" so there is no need to share it at run time!